# How to make a node replace another in chronological order?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sktexture

Lets say I have five dice like so:[image]

When I tap, Id like the die face with one dot to replace the one with two dots and (moving the 1 die across the row while moving the other die down the row) and if the last die is at the end, get it to replace the first die in the row. Would replacing the SKTextures have something to do with this? Thank you in advance.

Edit:

```
     override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
       let texRight = SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "DieFace1"))
        DieFace2.runAction(texRight)


    }

}
```

Edit 2:

```
    import SpriteKit

     var arrayOfDieFaces = [onE, twO, threE, fouR, fivE]


    class GameScene: SKScene {



      }



    func replace() {
    var count = 1
    while count <= 5 {
        let changeTexture = SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "Dice\(count)"))
        if count == 5 {
            arrayOfDieFaces[0].runAction(changeTexture)
        }
        else{
            arrayOfDieFaces[count].runAction(changeTexture)
        }
        count += 1
    }
    arrayOfDieFaces.append(arrayOfDieFaces[0])
    arrayOfDieFaces.dropFirst()

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {





    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

        replace()

    }


}
```

Comment: By changing the textures, you lose the ability to uniquely identify each dice (if that's what you want at some point).

Comment: Yes, I would like to identify each one with a physics body (bit masks). Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach changes the position of each dice instead of changing its texture. By changing the positions, it maintains the ability to uniquely identify each dice (e.g., by name).

First, create an `SKNode` called `dice` and define the size and spacing between each dice.

```
let dice = SKNode()
let diceSize = CGSizeMake(10, 10)
let spacing:CGFloat = 2
```

Second, create your dice nodes and add them, in order, to the `dice` `SKNode` and set the positions of each dice with

```
for i in 0..<6 {
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode ...
    sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody( ...
    sprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt32(0x1 << i)
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i)*(diceSize.width+spacing) , 0)
    dice.addChild (sprite)
}
// Center SKNode in the view
dice.position = CGPointMake (CGRectGetMidX(view.frame),CGRectGetMidY(view.frame))
addChild (dice)
```

Note that the position of each dice is based on the position of the node within the array.

Lastly, add the following to your code.

```
func rotate() {
    // Get last element in the array
    if let last = dice.children.last {
        // Remove the last dice from the SKNode
        last.removeFromParent()
        // Move the last to the front of the array
        dice.insertChild(last, atIndex: 0)
        // Update the positions of the 
        for i in 0..<dice.children.count {
            dice.children[i].position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i)*(diceSize.width+spacing) , 0)
        }
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {        
    for _ in touches {
        rotate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, well I see a `removeFromParent` in here and thats not what I'm looking to do. Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but I'm just looking to shift the positions, not add/subtract any node from the scene.

Comment: It immediately adds the node back into the node tree at the new position (i.e., in front of its siblings). Have you tried the above code?

Comment: Oh okay, now I understand. I haven't yet, sorry I've been busy but I will in just a little bit.

Comment: This is giving me an NSInvalidArgumentException: Attempted to add  a node which already has a parent. I only have each node called once though. Have you tested this?

Comment: The code works. The error occurs when you called `addChild` twice on the same node. I provided the for-loop as an example of how to set the initial positions of the dice. You will need to integrate that into your code.

Comment: Okay, but where does that for loop go? In my didMoveToView?

Comment: And I never called 'addChild' twice on the same node.

Comment: WAIT ok I figured it out. But its just giving me all of the die faces with one dot on them in a row. How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it working now? If not, please post the code that you use to create the dice.

Comment: Yes, it's working perfectly! It just took some tinkering (: thanks so much!

Comment: I added `categoryBitMask` to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work (not tested) assuming your DieFaces are from 1 to 6:

```
var arrayOfDieFaces = [DieFace1, DieFace2, DieFace3, DieFace4, DieFace5, DieFace6]


func changeTextures() {
    var count = 1
    while count <= 6 {
        let changeTexture = SKAction.setTexture(SKTexture(imageNamed: "DieFace\(count)"))
        if count == 6 {
            arrayOfDieFaces[0].runAction(changeTexture)
        }
        else{
            arrayOfDieFaces[count].runAction(changeTexture)
        }
        count += 1
    }
    arrayOfDieFaces.append(arrayOfDieFaces[0])
    arrayOfDieFaces.dropFirst()
}
```

Just call this fucntion inside the `touchesBegan()` function.

Comment: No problem! (It gave me +25 reputation ;)  )

Comment: It works wonderfully, but how do I make it so that they change every time the screen is tapped? Do I need to call the function more than once?

Comment: Because it only moves them over once and then when I tap again nothing happens.

Comment: Where do you call the function? Inside the touchesbegan function?

Comment: You should add the code for the array on top of your class, and not inside the touchesbegan function, that should do the trick

Comment: The 'var diceArray'? I did that (exactly what you explained) and it's not doing what I'd hoped.

Comment: That's strange, I will look at that as soon as I can. Could you post your relevant code?

Comment: Absolutely . Thanks tons

Comment: Edited. I changed some of the variables to fit my code.

Comment: Why is your gameScene code outside of your scene? (for example the touchesBegan())

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda rushing and I missed that bracket. Ignore it please.

Comment: I couldn't comment underneath Epsilons answer: make sure you create the sprites like this: `let sprite = SKSpriteNode(SKTexture(imageNamed:"DieFace\(i)"))`

Comment: Where does this go? In my didMoveToView?

Comment: Yup, and inside the for i 0...6 loop